# Msi doesn't run on a remote server with psexec : msiexec exit with code 0

Tags: powershell, psexec, windows-installer

I am trying to install a .msi on a remote server using the following command :

```
psexec \\computername -u adminname -p password -s -i msiexec.exe /i C:\share\myfile.msi
```

When I launch it I see the msiexec.exe process in process explorer on the remote but the process seems to be idle, and it stays like this until I close the parent process (psexec). 
I know that that msi create some folder in the C:\ drive of the remote machine directly so maybe a problem with the admin right ? The -u and -p I am giving have admin rights on the remote.

`psexec  -u adminname -p password -s -i msiexec.exe /i C:\share\myfile.msi` works if I type it on the remote directly. Any thing I am doing wrong ?

**Update :** if I remove the -i I get msiexec.exe exit with code 0 just after launching psexec.

**Update 2** : I have tried to perform the same action on the same server using c# and WMI and I get the following error : A security package specific error occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070721) maybe both of them are from the same issue/security option.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved my issue by copying the msi file to the remote server.

```
Copy-Item FileToInstall.msi -Destination \\Server\C$\DestinationFolder
psexec \\Server cmd /c "msiexec.exe /i C:\DestinationFolder\FileToInstall.msi /quiet /norestart"
```

Answer (score 0):

Psexec needs to know the remote working directory (-w) try :
`psexec \\computername -u adminname -p password -w c:\share -s -i msiexec.exe /i myfile.msi`

Answer (score 0):

You shoul add /qn! To suppress the ui and add /l*v log.txt to generate a log file

Answer (score 0):

Try also passing -h to force elevation. It fixed the same problem for me! In your case:

> psexec \\computername ***-h*** -u adminname -p password -w c:\share -s -i
>   msiexec.exe /i myfile.msi

Comment: psexec has no -h option now